# Where is my Mortarboard Badge?

Tags: support, badges, daily-reputation-badges

According to https://stackoverflow.com/users/3987441/lea-tano?tab=reputation I earned 220 reputation points yesterday and yet I'm not seeing the Mortarboard Badge?

Something else I'm wondering too...  if 200 is the daily rep limit how is it that I got 220?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The association bonus does not count towards the daily reputation badges.

So you only earned 120 qualifying reputation that day.

Comment: The badge description should explicitly state that fact, but it does not. It says: [Earn at least 200 reputation (the daily maximum) in a single day](http://i.imgur.com/h2LlI2H.png)